# check if value exists at index in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

This is probably an easy question but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere.

Let's say I have a numpy array like below:

```
x = np.array([[2,3],[1,0],[5,6]])
```

I am looking for a way to say if a value exists in x do something.

For example

if x[2][1] exists do something:
This happens because it exists (and has a 6 value)

if x[4][2] exists do something:
This does not happen because it does not exist (but does not throw an error)

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use x.shape(). This returns a tuple with the dimensions, so in your example, you only need to check if 4<x.shape()[0] and 2<x.shape()[1].

Answer (score 1):

```
In [114]: x = np.array([[2,3],[1,0],[5,6]])
In [115]: x[2][1]
Out[115]: 6
In [116]: x[2,1]                # more idiomatic indexing
Out[116]: 6
```

Indexing out of bounds does raise an error:

```
In [117]: x[4][2]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-117-74efee77abf6>", line 1, in <module>
    x[4][2]
IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3

In [118]: x[4,2]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-118-97c89dcf326d>", line 1, in <module>
    x[4,2]
IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3
```

Comment: I know the shape of my array it is 28x28.  What I actually trying to do is write a blurring function that takes the average of the 8 digits around it and itself.  The problem is the edges do not have 8 digits around them so I need something that accounts for this.

Comment: I was trying to write two loops where if the value index didn't exist it would just skip it.

Comment: If you are indexing with slices, you can end up with an 'empty' window, e.g. `arr[26:29, 28:32]`.  That is you can 'slice' off the edge without warning (that's true for Python lists as well).  Sounds like this is a bigger task, one involving `convolving` and other image processing.  If `numpy` doesn't have the tools, you may want to look in `scipy` or other sci-kit.